# Infinite ajax scroll with lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, infinite-scroll

Hi guys I'm using infiniteajaxscroll to load my photos on scroll down, the problem is the lightbox I'm using wont work on loaded pages.

My ininiteajaxscroll jquery

```
var ias = $.ias({
  container :'.wrap', // main container where data goes to append
  item:'.box-foto', // single items
  pagination:'.paginacao', // page navigation
  next:'.paginacao a', // next page selector
  text: 'LOAD MORE PHOTOS'
});


ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension( ));
ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({offset: 10}));
```

This is my lightbox code: http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/

```
function zoomPhotos(){

  $("#list-photos-int").lightGallery({
    thumbnail:true,
    selector: '.box-thumb'
  });
}
```

How can I use both components together on loaded pages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load lightgallery in a callback like this:

```
ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
$("#list-photos-int").lightGallery({
thumbnail:true,
selector: '.box-thumb'
});
});
```